# How can the default font size for a family be set?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I want to use the luximono font for all my listings and all verbatims. By default, this font seems to be bigger than the rest, so I adjusted my listings with `basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize` which I could also do for all `\verb`'s. How can I set the default font size for a family, in this case `ttfamily`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to use the `scaled` option of the `luximono` package, to scale the font provided by the package.